# Update flutter dependencies in /.pub-cache

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I erased in my folder `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/this_plugin`

**What is the command to update the dependencies inside `pubsec.yaml`?**  I believe it is

> flutter packages get

The folder under `.pub-cache` is still not up to date.

Note: there was a `pubspec.lock` that I deleted

Answer (score 244, accepted):

> Disclaimer: By running the command below, have a really fast internet
> connection or be ready to lose one hour of productive hours. ( it will
> redownload every package every installed on your pc, and I mean each
> and all of the versions of each packages)~TSR

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

or delete `/Users/xxxxxxx/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.8.2+3/` and run `flutter packages get` again.

if all the above things fail delete the cache folder or also check the version updated in the lock file (some time lock give me the problem with updating the version number)

PS:
[Why flutter pub cache repair download every package version previously used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624795/why-flutter-pub-cache-repair-downloads-every-package-version-previously-used)

Comment: ```Failed to reactivate dartfn 0.4.4: Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/yogiarifwidodo/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dartfn-0.4.4".```

Answer (score 93):

Remove the package from `dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml`, run `flutter packages get`. And then add the package to `dependencies` again and running `flutter packages get`.This process has solved the problem for me in the past.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Yes, LOG_TAG's answer explains why this works and a better legit way of doing this.

Comment: won't work if you changed some file of package, as on pub get it will first check-in cache better to use flutter pub cache repair

Comment: It will not work in all cases, try running , flutter pub cache repair

Comment: Was skeptical at first, I don't know how, but this worked like magic 100%.

Comment: Although this is worked for me for most of the times, sometimes it doesn't work. In my case I was adding lets say the version 1.1.alpha-1.0 on my pubspec, but I was still getting the version version 1.1.alpha-2.0, even with the above trick. What helped me was to go to pubspec.lock and change there the version to the desired one. Then flutter pub get got me the right version.

Answer (score 72):

This steps worked for me

Delete the `pubspec.lock` file then run the command `flutter pub get` again.

Comment: This approach resolved my problem with syncfusion_flutter_calendar plug-in

Comment: This approach resolved my problem with the syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer plugin, thank you very much!

Comment: Tried, did not work for me

Answer (score 43):

### Clearing the projects cache

You can empty the entire projects cache to reclaim extra disk space or remove problematic packages.

run `flutter pub cache clean` in terminal at project directory

Comment: It works fine. is is better than others.

Answer (score 21):

The below steps worked for me.

**Flutter installation corrupted**
The Flutter install directory is in an inconsistent state and that causes all kinds of troubles.

**Causes**
Unclear

**Ways to fix**
Run the following commands in the Flutter install directory:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

**Corrupted cache**
Especially with plugin packages, it was seen several times that the package in the pub cache was corrupted.

**Symptoms**
Usually syntax errors at build time about code in dependencies.

**Causes**
Unknown.
IDEs or editors used by developers might not prevent editing plugin files and when they navigate into plugin code they might accidentally modify the code.

**Ways to fix**

Run `flutter pub cache repair`
This might take quite some time and re-downloads every package in the cache, even outdated versions that might not be used anymore by any project on disk.

Delete `~/.pub-cache/hosted` and/or `~/.pub-cache/git` (for Git dependencies). This requires running flutter packages to get in all active projects on your machine afterward.

Delete a specific package or package version. Look up the exact path in the cache for a specific package in the .packages file of your project. For example for firebase_auth

***Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted***

Answer (score 2):

Error:
Found an existing Pub cache at ... It can be repaired by running `dart pub cache repair`. It can be reset by running `dart pub cache clean`.

Solution:
Run following command in the flutter project directory
`dart pub cache repair` then
`dart pub cache clean` and then
`flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

I unable to install flutter while installing following error generated
Found an existing Pub cache at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache.
It can be repaired by running `dart pub cache repair`.
It can be reset by running `dart pub cache clean`.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following command in the terminal for Mac users:

open ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/

Delete the problematic package folders. Then, run the project again.

Answer (score -1):

run

> flutter clean

> flutter pub cache clean

delete pubspec.lock file  then check again