# Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1, When I updated Flutter SDK to v1.12.13+hotfix.5

Tags: flutter

Compiler message:
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^
../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/shutter/Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 780
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command '/Users/shutter/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Any solution to solve the problem above?

Comment: run flutter doctor and show me what happens. if you have android studio. open the android directory in android studio also

Comment: Salma: It's seem like nothing error.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399209/update-flutter-dependencies-in-pub-cache

Answer (score 2):

Just replace **cached_network_image:1.1.3** with  **cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc** in your pubspec.yaml file, refer [this](https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/270) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter v1.12.13 is having issues

I have resolved this issue by doing following changes

1. Switch to master channel of flutter
2. Update flutter to 1.13.5
3. created new project
4. copy paste old files into new project
5. Voila it's worked