# Why flutter pub cache repair downloads every package version previously used?

Tags: flutter, dart

The command `flutter pub cache repair` downloads every package version previously used, even of libraries that I no longer use. Why?

Is there any way to clean everything and download only the last packages version?

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, Dart development team believes that disk space problems are a thing of the past, and does not provide a standard command to clear the global cache.

Therefore, there is only one way - it is to clear the folder `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org` yourself. You can then reinstall packages for each actual application separately.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "You can then reinstall packages for each actual application separately."?