# Flutter on Mac OS package issues

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that runs on android and uses several plugins which work perfectly and all of them have support for iOS. I am trying to run it on a Mac using VSCode and its throwing a bunch of errors saying it can't find packages that are there. I am trying to start with one, fix it and then move to the next but after adding the proper Key / Value pairs for the Device_Calendar plugin in `info.plist` but it is not fixing it.

> ### ERROR
>
> **lib/calendar/calendars.dart:1:8: Error: Error when reading '../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_calendar-3.0.0+1/lib/device_calendar.dart': No such file or directory
>   import 'package:device_calendar/device_calendar.dart';**

Here is the plugin:

```
import 'package:device_calendar/device_calendar.dart';
```

I added this to info.plist :

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>INSERT_REASON_HERE</string>
```

plugin - device_calendar 3.0.0+3

Comment: Did you add the package to your `pubspec.yaml` file and run `flutter packages get`?

Comment: Yeah I did , I ran cache too still same issue

Comment: You look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399209/update-flutter-dependencies-in-pub-cache