# scroll_to_index-2.1.1: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, pubspec

I'm trying to implement integration testing for my flutter app but I'm getting this error when writing something very straightforward.

`ERROR: ../../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/scroll_to_index-2.1.1/lib/scroll_to_index.dart:358:57: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.`

Please help me in resolving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because of Flutter SDK upgrade, it you are using Flutter SDK 3.0 then [scroll_to_index](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index/versions) is still not upgradable or if you are using Flutter 2.0 then you can simply run this command `flutter pub upgrade`

Comment: Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.731 is what I'm using. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also I don even have scroll_to_index in my dependencies ;-;

Comment: @Nike then this may be issue because of pub cache, did you try to delete pubspec.lock file and `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

Comment: If above issue still not fixing your problem then you can repair your cache but it will re download all the package are available inn cache, for more about cache clear you can look into this question  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399209/update-flutter-dependencies-in-pub-cache