# Flutter no longer builds in ios or android after using firebase realtime

Tags: flutter, firebase, bloc, flutter-bloc

**Problem**

I have been successfully using firebase ***firestore*** in my current app for  months. However, recently when experimenting with firebase ***realtime***, when I attempt to build on either physical or emulated iphone or android, the build fails.

I've tried usual - flutter clean, multiple emulators, reboot everything, same errors.

Strangely, when building with a pre-realtime version, the errors persist - none of my previous commits work anymore!

For sanity check, I created a new flutter application to see if *anything* was working - yes, a new clean flutter app works.

Any advice?

**Error message when trying to build for iPhone:**

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/qp/f66_vfps3839pj76pb3d_9fr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.u3vUGq/flutter_ios_build_temp_di
        r4QxZbF/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:21:38: Error: Type
    'FutureOr' not found.
    typedef EventHandler<Event, State> = FutureOr<void> Function(
                                         ^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_base.dart:23:3: Error:
    Type 'FutureOr' not found.
      FutureOr<void> close();
      ^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:108:44:
    Error: Type 'StreamTransformerBase' not found.
    class _FlatMapStreamTransformer<T> extends StreamTransformerBase<Stream<T>, T> {
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:53:28: Error:
    Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController'.
      final _eventController = StreamController<Event>.broadcast();
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:54:27: Error:
    'StreamSubscription' isn't a type.
      final _subscriptions = <StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_base.dart:61:57: Error:
    Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController.broadcast'.
      late final _stateController = StreamController<State>.broadcast();
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:3:24:
    Error: Undefined name 'runZoned'.
    const _asyncRunZoned = runZoned;
                           ^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:68:22: Error:
    Method not found: 'Completer'.
      final _completer = Completer<void>();
                         ^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:69:25: Error:
    'FutureOr' isn't a type.
      final _disposables = <FutureOr<void> Function()>[];
                            ^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:196:48: Error:
    Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController.broadcast'.
            final controller = StreamController<E>.broadcast(
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:269:57: Error: The
    method 'cancel' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
     - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'cancel'.
        await Future.wait<void>(_subscriptions.map((s) => s.cancel()));
                                                            ^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:37:40:
    Error: Undefined name 'Zone'.
      static BlocOverrides? get current => Zone.current[_token] as BlocOverrides?;
                                           ^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:103:33:
    Error: The argument type '_FlatMapStreamTransformer<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter
    type 'StreamTransformer<Stream<dynamic>, dynamic>'.
     - '_FlatMapStreamTransformer' is from 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart'
     ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart').
     - 'StreamTransformer' is from 'dart:async'.
     - 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
          .transform<dynamic>(const _FlatMapStreamTransformer<dynamic>());
                                    ^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:113:44:
    Error: Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController.broadcast'.
        final controller = StreamController<T>.broadcast(sync: true);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:116:30:
    Error: 'StreamSubscription' isn't a type.
          final subscriptions = <StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:145:28:
    Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type
    'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>'.
     - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
     - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
     - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
            return Future.wait(cancels).then((_) {});
                               ^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:80:23: Error:
    The method 'Completer' isn't defined for the class '_Emitter<State>'.
     - '_Emitter' is from 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart'
     ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
    'Completer'.
        final completer = Completer<void>();
                          ^^^^^^^^^
    ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:88:23: Error:
    The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type
    'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>'.
     - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
     - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
     - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
        return Future.any([future, completer.future]).whenComplete(() {
                          ^
    Failed to package /Users/stew/Repos/pet_project.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/qp/f66_vfps3839pj76pb3d_9fr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.u3vUGq/flutter_ios_build_temp_di
        r4QxZbF/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
```

**Error message when trying to build for Android:**

```
Launching lib/main_development.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:21:38: Error: Type 'FutureOr' not found.
typedef EventHandler<Event, State> = FutureOr<void> Function(
                                     ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_base.dart:23:3: Error: Type 'FutureOr' not found.
  FutureOr<void> close();
  ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:108:44: Error: Type 'StreamTransformerBase' not found.
class _FlatMapStreamTransformer<T> extends StreamTransformerBase<Stream<T>, T> {
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:53:28: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController'.
  final _eventController = StreamController<Event>.broadcast();
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:54:27: Error: 'StreamSubscription' isn't a type.
  final _subscriptions = <StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_base.dart:61:57: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController.broadcast'.
  late final _stateController = StreamController<State>.broadcast();
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:3:24: Error: Undefined name 'runZoned'.
const _asyncRunZoned = runZoned;
                       ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:68:22: Error: Method not found: 'Completer'.
  final _completer = Completer<void>();
                     ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:69:25: Error: 'FutureOr' isn't a type.
  final _disposables = <FutureOr<void> Function()>[];
                        ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:196:48: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController.broadcast'.
        final controller = StreamController<E>.broadcast(
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart:269:57: Error: The method 'cancel' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'cancel'.
    await Future.wait<void>(_subscriptions.map((s) => s.cancel()));
                                                        ^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:37:40: Error: Undefined name 'Zone'.
  static BlocOverrides? get current => Zone.current[_token] as BlocOverrides?;
                                       ^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:103:33: Error: The argument type '_FlatMapStreamTransformer<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamTransformer<Stream<dynamic>, dynamic>'.
 - '_FlatMapStreamTransformer' is from 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart').
 - 'StreamTransformer' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
      .transform<dynamic>(const _FlatMapStreamTransformer<dynamic>());
                                ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:113:44: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'StreamController.broadcast'.
    final controller = StreamController<T>.broadcast(sync: true);
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:116:30: Error: 'StreamSubscription' isn't a type.
      final subscriptions = <StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc_overrides.dart:145:28: Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
        return Future.wait(cancels).then((_) {});
                           ^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:80:23: Error: The method 'Completer' isn't defined for the class '_Emitter<State>'.
 - '_Emitter' is from 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/bloc.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Completer'.
    final completer = Completer<void>();
                      ^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bloc-8.0.3/lib/src/emitter.dart:88:23: Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
    return Future.any([future, completer.future]).whenComplete(() {
                      ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/stew/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/stew/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDevelopmentDebug'...                  19.2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevelopmentDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Update flutter dependencies in /.pub-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399209/update-flutter-dependencies-in-pub-cache)

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).