# After doing pub get it keeps happening but pub get is not happening anymore I have attached picture below

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-pubspec

After doing pub get it keeps happening but pub get is not happening anymore I have attached picture below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jozJS.png)

After doing pub get it keeps happening but pub get is not happening anymore I have attached picture below.

Comment: Check your internet connection. If that is okay then wait some time . it will resolved

Comment: you can also try to read this thread (about cache) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399209/update-flutter-dependencies-in-pub-cache or you can also try to make sure all you other depenencies are ok. or even make sure you have no errors in `pubspec.yaml`